# Knockout containerless control for custom binding handler

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I created custom binding handler "foreachprop"

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachprop = {
transformObject: function (obj) {
    var properties = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            properties.push({ key: key, value: obj[key] });
        }
    }
    return properties;
},
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
        properties = ko.bindingHandlers.foreachprop.transformObject(value);
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: properties });
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
};
```

If i iterate through object

```
<div data-bind="foreachprop: sections"></div>
```

This works, 
However if i use containerless control, it is not working for same data

```
<!-- ko foreachprop: sections --> <!-- /ko -->
```

How to use continerless control flow for custom binding handlers

Jsfiddle created new http://jsfiddle.net/E6xq2/5/

Comment: There is no knouckout in your JSFiddle. Have you posted the correct link?

Comment: Please check your fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E6xq2/5/ check this fiddle, i created a new one to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html

First, tell Knockout to allow your binding on virtual elements:

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.foreachprop = true;
```

Then, if necessary, rewrite your binding to use the virtual element APIs.

Comment: This is not working, can you please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E6xq2/5/

Comment: Sure it is.  Change ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.randomOrder = true; to ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.foreachprop = true;  See: http://jsfiddle.net/E6xq2/6/

Comment: Yes, Its working. Thanks. I missed that section of the documentation.